# Python command working but why?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I have a simple code that goes like this in Python:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]

def union(a,b):
    pos = 0
    while pos < len(b):
        n = b[pos]
        if n in a is not 'True':
            a = a
        else:
            a.append(n)
        pos = pos +1
    return a

print union(a,b)
```

As you can see, the first IF statement makes no sense. However, if I code it this way:

```
if n in a is 'True':
    a.append(n)
```

it does not work. The first code segment changes a = [1,2,4,6]  - only adding numbers from list 'b' that are not in list 'a' already. If I change the 'IF' snippet to "is 'True" as suggested, it does not work.

While this function does what I intended it to do, I feel it is not clean and I have no idea why "if n in a is 'True':" would not behave equal to the else part of the "if n in a is not 'True':" function.

Can somebody please help me understand this?

Answer (score 3):

It is not a very pythonic way to use boolean check and then compare it with a string, so it would be better to do it this way:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]

def union(x,y):
    for v in y:
        if v not in x:
            x.append(v)
    return x

print union(a,b)
```

OR:

```
a.extend(set(b).difference(set(a)))
print a
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

OR in case you don't care about new objects creating than:

```
print list(set(a).union(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

`in` and `is`/`is not` are both **relational operators**, and in Python relational operators are chained. Therefore `n in a is not 'True'` is equivalent to `n in a and a is not 'True'`, and `n in a is 'True'` is equivalent to `n in a and a is 'True'`. Clearly these are not negations of each other since they both have `n in a`.

But don't use `is` unless you know you need it, and never compare against a boolean either (unless yadda yadda).

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `True` not the string `'True'`

or better yet, just

```
if n not in a:
    a.append(n)
```

If you are a beginner, you may not realise that Python has a builtin type called [`set`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

`set` objects already have methods for intersection/union etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if n in a
```

or

```
if n not in a
```

instead of the `is 'True'`.